# javascript event for mobile navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website which for mobile devices uses a bootstrap feature (left sidebar) which pops up when clicking the button (see figures below). I don't know much about bootstrap, but I would like to link a javascript event to the left sidebar being visible. How can I check within javascript whether this bar is visible?
I would like to use the change() function, but I do not know what the bootstrap js actually uses to show the menu bar...
The html for the button is

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="padding-left:6px;">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-recalc="true" data-target=".navmenu" data-canvas=".canvas">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

and the html for the left sidebar is

```
<div class="navmenu navmenu-inverse navmenu-fixed-left" id="mobile_navbar">
    <a class="navmenu-brand" href="/">Benty-fields</a>
    <ul class="nav navmenu-nav">
    content
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to detect when someone clicks on the button.
Just add an ID to the button, then :

```
$("#buttonId").click(function(e) {
    // your javascript event
});
```

Alternatively, if you want to check if the menu is visible at any time, you could set a variable (bool) in your javascript event and check that value when needed.

Here is another approach :

```
var isVisible = $("#myDiv").is( ":visible" ); 
var isHidden = $("#myDiv").is( ":hidden" );
```

Comment: Hi John yes I thought about this as well, but to make the menu disappear the user does not need to click the button (the user can click anywhere outside the menubar)... therefore using that button click event does not work very well. I would like to use the change() function but I do not know what the bootstrap js actually changes when showing the menu bar?

Comment: you can try using F12 in your browser to see the changes done in the HTML when the menu is made visible/invisible